# MySQL - как сделать группировку по полю в запросе с несколькими SELECT?

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести таблицу с данными:
Офис, Кол-во клиентов, Кол-во закрытых клиентов, Сумма закрытых клиентов.
Всего две таблицы - в одной лежит значение Офиса (список значений), во второй - ID клиентов и суммы по ним. Таблицы имеют связь по ID, то есть table_1.ID=table_2.VALUE_ID
Получилось вывести три столбца (Кол-во клиентов, Кол-во закрытых клиентов, Сумма закрытых клиентов), не могу вывести Офис и сгруппировать по нему.
Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(table_1.ID) from table_1 where table_1.DATE_CREATE >= UTC_DATE() and table_1.DATE_CREATE <= DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as 'Кол-во клиентов',
(SELECT count(table_1.ID) from table_1 where table_1.CLOSEDATE >= UTC_DATE() and table_1.CLOSEDATE <= DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as 'Кол-во закрытых',
(SELECT SUM(table_1.OPPORTUNITY) from table_1 where table_1.CLOSEDATE >= UTC_DATE() and table_1.CLOSEDATE <= DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as 'Сумма закрытых'
```

Как вывести четвертое значение (Офис) из второй таблицы и сгруппировать по нему?

Comment: MySQL какой(версия)?

Comment: MySQL - 5.7.36-39

Comment: По нормальному и простому - никак.(с версии 8 если мне память не изменяет, появился нужный синтаксис).

Comment: а если не по нормальному?)

Comment: А зачем надо было городить огород с кучей подзапросов? есть же условное агрегирование...

Comment: а если не по нормальному - допишите еще один подзапрос, запихните его значение в переменную и групируйте по созданной переменной, скорее всего придется в еще один подзапрос обернуть всё, но это не точно (mySQL указанной версии позволял создавать обновлять и читать значение переменной в пределах одного запроса)

Comment: Akina
можно натолкнуть где посмотреть?

Comment: Владимир Клыков
пробовал так делать, но к сожалению либо не верно связи делаю, либо нельзя так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT SUM(date_create BETWEEN UTC_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as 'Кол-во клиентов',
       SUM(closedate BETWEEN UTC_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as 'Кол-во закрытых',
       SUM(CASE WHEN closedate BETWEEN UTC_DATE() AND DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                THEN opportunity
                ELSE 0 
                END) as 'Сумма закрытых'
FROM table_1
-- WHERE closedate >= UTC_DATE()
--   AND date_create <= DATE_ADD(UTC_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

JOIN в этот запрос ещё одной таблицы при условии связи 1:1 не представляет сложностей. Если же в этой ещё одной таблице может быть более одной соотв. записи, то показанный запрос использовать как подзапрос.

Если условие `date_create <= closedate` верное - раскомментируйте WHERE. Всё серверу меньше работы.

Comment: у меня вопрос был как добавить еще один столбец в результат и сгруппировать по нему) 
мой вариант также работает, там уже всё считается, но вот с еще одним столбцом не могу победить...

Comment: @Станислав Проверьте логику моего запроса. Если решите, что она верна - добавьте в него ещё один столбец, это должно быть несложно. И вообще, надо было озвучивать задачу, а не только свою попытку её решить. Типичная XY-problem.

Comment: у меня описано в задаче, что нужно как-то добавить еще один столбец в результат и что с тремя текущими я справился) сложность как раз таки в выводе еще одного значения и группировке по нему....( буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: получилось, спасибо